Consumir web service afip en asp.net
Hola buenas como estan? disculpen necesitaba cualquierr ayuda posible, estoy haciendo una web core api para mi frontend con asp.net y entre varias funciones queria agregar la de facturar con afip, entendi que tengo que generar certificado de testing desde wsass que hice, agregue tambien la direccion del web service a mi proyecto como referencia de web service, me genero una clase pero ahora sinceramente no se como proceder, lei sobre como generar el ticket y todo eso pero no se nisiquiera donde deberia poner el codigo ni como deberia aplicarlo a mi sistema de gestion o si deberia aplicarlo en mis controllers o en el set de datos del usuario que factura, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

El WS es SOAP? como se llama la clase que te generó?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

si, es SOAP, se creo la clase Reference.cs

Este blog tiene una explicación completa de como hacerlo https://exgetmessage.blogspot.com/2018/02/conectar-tu-aplicacion-con-afip-sin.html
